# When manipulating large arrays in a finite recursive loop, what point should I switch from stack to heap?

Tags: c++, heap-memory, stack-memory

I am *very* new to C++ and am trying to optimise the speed of a program which performs calculations on elements in a large one-dimensional array in a recursive loop. In fact the one-dimensional array is storing the values of a 3D matrix, each value a floating point. The dimensions of the matrices may be up to 1500 x 2000 x 200.

I have read that stack memory may be read faster than heap memory, but is there a size limit at which it becomes inefficient or even unpracticable, assuming I set the stack size large enough to hold all the data?

Thanks for your help, and apologies if this is a stupid question!

PS If you can suggest any other techniques I should look into to speed up my program, I would be much obliged!

Comment: Those are large enough numbers that you can start worrying about stuff like accessing the matrix in chunks that fit in the L1/L2 caches etc :)

Comment: I am *very new to C* and when asking I tag questions with *C++*... I recommend that you focus on one of the languages and learn it, choose either, but mixing them will get you the worst of both worlds (i.e. you might end up using C++ as if it was C or viceversa)

Comment: Sorry, typo! I meant c++ in the post! :-)

Comment: What calculations are you doing, exactly? A 1500 * 2000 * 200 matrix of 32-bit floats is over 2 GB. Just iterating over that is going to take longer than you probably want. If you scatter the accesses it gets even worse, but without details it's impossible to suggest anything.

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference in speed between stack and heap memory. The best way to optimize the code is to traverse the arrays in a linear fashion to maximize cache utilization.

Comment: Hmm, it depends.  If you're talking about *local* stack, then it can potentially be faster, as it can be addressed with immediates.

Comment: @Oli - this should impact the opcode size, but I doubt that with today's pipelining there would be much of a difference in accessing local or remote memory address...

Comment: @Eli: I'm not brave enough to construct a counterexample.  However, if there are dependencies between consecutive reads (e.g. walking a linked-list), then I would imagine that CPU pipelining won't be much help.  Note that by "local", I mean the stack of the currently-executing scope (not "local" in a physical sense).

Comment: @Oli How do you mean? Either a variable is in a register, L1, L2 or uncached memory. The probability of it being in any of those places can of course vary with how you structure the code but there's no intrinsic differnce between stack and heap memory, right?

Comment: @Andreas: Well, firstly it depends what platform we're talking about.  But what I'm getting at is that for `x[idx]`, if `x` is a stack variable, it can be accessed as (made-up pseudocode): `ADD esp, idx, eax; LD eax`.  If it's a heap variable (i.e. a pointer), then it becomes e.g. `ADD esp, -8, eax; LD eax; ADD eax, idx, eax; LD eax`.

Comment: @Oli It *might* require fewer instructions to read a *single* value from an array or other variable on the stack. Once you have the memory address in a register, there's no difference though (just made a small toy example in MSVC and checked the disassembly).

Answer (score 1):

> is there a size limit at which it becomes inefficient or even unpracticable, assuming I set the stack size large enough to hold all the data?

No. You might want to change the recursive loop into an iterative loop, though. Unless its a tail recursive loop and the compiler is smart enough to optimize it, which g++ does starting at -O2, for example.

Comment: Thanks for spotting another dopey error in my post...it is in fact iterative, not recursive! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Stack variables might, indeed, be read faster than heap variables *within the function* they are defined in. All other functions only receive a pointer/reference to the variable which is similar to what they would have for a heap-allocated variable.

It is generally unwise to put large variables on the stack, so I will suggest to take the conservative approach and put your array on the heap (use a `std::vector`, for example).

Finally, this small difference is very unlikely to affect the overall speed of your program.

---

Optimization is generally the domain of experts, or at least people who dig enough into profilers and have sufficient understanding of the underlying language semantics and hardware and how the translation is done from high-level to low-level... Experts, or wannabe experts then :)

- *prefer optimizing the algorithm* rather than its implementation (to begin with)
- *don't jump (randomly) around memory*

If your function is still too slow, then... post some code! Though it may be better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This is a cache issue, not that local variables are stored in another type of memory than variables allocated from the heap. In the case of traversing a large array, there will be no difference.